# Duplicate symbol error when linking C code

Tags: c, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to use some functions that are written in C. However I am getting the following error message:

```
duplicate symbol _getInt in:
    /Users/<redacted>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-ecbrpcljzanjildnvawnrcgejdwn/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/source.o
    /Users/<redacted>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-ecbrpcljzanjildnvawnrcgejdwn/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/swift.o
    ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

swift.swift:

```
print(getInt())
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef header_h_
#define header_h_
#include "source.c"
#endif
```

source.c:

```
int getInt() {
    return 4;
}
```

These are my bridging header settings
[image]

Comment: Why are you including a .c file in a .h file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header should never include a `.c` file.

`.c` files should include `.h` files.

Each `.c` file is its own "compilation unit". The compiler compiles all compilation units separately. You would include `source.h` in `source.c`, so that the header serves to provide the forward declarations of the functions implements in the compilation unit.

If you include `source.c` in `source.h`, then every compilation unit that includes `source.h` (including `source.c`) would get its own copy of the implementations defined in `source.c`. That means there would be multiple definitions of the same things, and the compiler wouldn't know which one to pick. That's why you're getting this "duplicate" symbol error. I suspect both `swift.c` and `source.c` include `source.h`.